# Ubuntu insufficient disk space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking

I am getting an insufficient disk space error, here is my `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        29G   28G   31M 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            6.9G   12K  6.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.4G  364K  1.4G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       133G   60M  126G   1% /mnt
```

It seems that the first one is full yet the last one is barely used, how to I make the last one usable for the current account?

Comment: Put files on it?

Comment: Can I mount /dev/sdb1 on / as well?

Comment: The command   `du -h -d 1` will show you the size of each directory on the system. Be sure to run it from the root directory `/`

Answer (score 2):

1. Find a directory that's using a lot of the space in /dev/sda1, for example /home or /var/lib.  `du -m /*` can help you find where the most space is used.
2. Move those files onto /dev/sdb1, so into /mnt as you currently have it mounted.
3. Dismount /dev/sdb1 from /mnt:

   ```
   umount /dev/sdb1
   ```
4. Remount /dev/sdb1 at the location where you want your moved files to be, for example /home.  To make the new mount permanent, add an entry in /etc/fstab, for example:

   ```
   /dev/sdb1  /home  ext4  1  1
   ```

   or edit the existing entry there for /dev/sdb1.  See `man fstab` for details.  Then `mount -a` will remount /dev/sdb1 at its new location.

Now your /home directory (for example) will have 133GB of space to use.